# Change text of PAGE N OF M Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a display problem
I put the special field "Page N of M"

but I dont want to display the word "Page" , i only want "N of M".

this field is displayed on the top of my report.

how can i do?.

Comment: can you create a formula that strips the first 5 characters of the special field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this.

```
Page Number / Total Page Count
```

From the special field

Answer (score 3):

Embed the "Page Number" and "Total Page Count" fields in a Text Object.  Both are located in the Special Fields hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

Easy way to put number of page in your crystal report

Insert ----> Special Field ------> add(Page N of M)

then insert again

Insert ----> Special Field ------> add(Page total count)

thank me later